# How to compose complex discriminated union types with generics into a single type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, composition, discriminated-union, nested-generics

### Background

I've been working on a library (see [`convert`](https://github.com/termsurf/task/blob/af2c9959833344651b35a5a6be19a7f336174a89/code/action/convert/node.internal.ts#L26) and [`format`](https://github.com/termsurf/task/blob/af2c9959833344651b35a5a6be19a7f336174a89/code/action/format/node.ts#L3) entrypoint functions if curious, not necessary though, the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMIEMA2O4DeAUHKZhIgG7CxwC8cA5AMYXWyMA0JZAYtKizwGjAGYChXIgF8iAejlwAcgHk4AUQBKmlZoBccACoALGsDgBJAMpwscMIgDmcALQA+OACswz1lRowNHAAJsCiAJaIwMFwplDARH4AzvAQyDBg6QCM9HDMuDgAFMRktsww4RQG2HgAdBhsAdylkZkwBiWlZOJQgu1MDo5SXd3hOMAdPCOlYELGBmIQEMPT0s1ka1NwaRnpk9NwPX0L3kPrIxHj+wdkszDzTABGWFC1pysjm6Wb0gCURPJFKoNNpdAZ7uEknBapdgLU7sY4JC4JRcOFgpw4IC4ElIsxzAB3czGLDUFFomI7NqHaBwCFQhr+Wj5OqJChJCDjWo4CCOQpU7IwsZwhH-bFaHT6IxxczIxAQexOVweYwwVD4PzsQJQEJhSLRWJmNmIFLbdJtABMuRZRU6pCw5UqiGqBXqjVg5yRiDa1wuEn6jEGHy6sN9NwRC3Ey09309XzIAv6dpD-oWqvVwdKocIWwOEaeL1q6ZwmY2ce4fwBChBkvBxmRQq5CKRUNUhnJOHRmOx6OABQAnkj4AS0jgYo9zDB+2ADVgoQADKLsee1Y0crk8vmJi2NkVzMXV4ESsHSswt2yIOAACUMAFkADI03pCbW6iJRYIAQjXqXSAGZrQKYotgdCoqkwV1+GfGBPSOIQ0zVEtPVYUIFgAHjANxTDwBURygMc0LkTDGBkA9FCsYxRxiEkySPUFNDXTk4U3fl-1qFDgDImsTxMM9kTbWw4AAImeKAhKfPpX1Cd9olqOSfzNGAABZALwYDSlAp0XTqKC+lg1MCygYMOMjJZalEqRKyIUBIFoOd+0QZhDmQRywMvG00K2dtQECRBggZApPQwBAQF8-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-XajblJtdSw+YAAdSa4x16r0ppd3sXXj7mdx-CYfj-9J-gBf4eL-ua+oHVvffe091Tv2giAnAv8r7eyribGuy80ZAI3u1MqjthaNxgVASW1t3bhVDuHSOSDIYxxZk9OAKciEGxIWAbOucC4EAkvBIwcAy7TArsAdgi9qb2Ucs5VyTpGEwFQbg9Ba9MF5S2ByKa+IDCUMNoYNw3AepbGSExbkvJChSKgPiOGX0wZTUvAwkyTBAgpCyBaP8jAWG2FEUITGj04FLxpog-09ijpSxURAVCOIYDEycAjSmTjzaryEJ-b+59L7-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-gPSoEgf-dAKd97QiPvhjCs2Q7nbtWmR3OAAA1XAyAv6bSQ20NWA6ENo2HRuoQuRiPIchDAaWjACojQVhKol3rD3+mVaq8jbRUqSw0KFI55QABC-YrDIEeAAaTDmzMg7H0goZglsCwEsGPOLpirFVIjvUkZgFx5MtG33dAMvJ+GpRf0ztIG9Aw6gQDMBwMgUIOHIrMegoa6jiZGAK0xBYROGwZD5zgIURguCrFqfwRHJjh0IOOY81sFOw6HN9Cc-5wOflXNbA6FZQlS0TTwAsLeX5ABxdQFacu5YsBgETFaLBKDSgAVUMBW3gugcvtgYNRoMmJGDvDa48VAYAuBMBXaIVzXrkh+oI4x69S6L37o07kQo5sQvZbywVorJWysVeq7V+rmhGu-Glrymg9HRsZdNAt-LhW8srYrSoGr626sNd+U1uALWnC9faz4F7XWeu5zWsNxTwTxu3oPWF1K9AtizdpvNorS3zulcu9dmrt2tv3Z23tqAB30vBOI4uq9u7Jt3ofaO5FejUBlJZfs2dPoW5Zn0zjlda6NNkOzAwwm1KlSsNIGzh6hUTOCJ3ReibtPAdYwAxce1hdmcYpYU+lFPIoANBcjARZozxWHeGzrFQSgNt3Ye9LLYo8YADc9IwLJBvdcjlEKIC0wZGBm5N6URgSRKBnF18ALJVuPtSC+1CH7h24UUHC30Gbc3CHq814jwwyOleo9+4hyK4GwN+6glB-H1JCekHiMT3FkL8Xvop9zszf7hchlF0zp16KSaS8MwmMLunTMGXA4XrMxfHX3AMI25wHPybR7RhZtZ-HBPCbE-2CTpBHxqYYTpsvTgADcnP+ht5n0Bgpg54ykADslSfjg-YMFH4l8KLlg7ygJJeFOhQ19B3vNR2jg2U6PnYewWqd+q4+5Xhh6z2GFH+2lsFyOOciBAA) should be enough) and have asked a few questions (here and on Reddit, for the less clear-cut-answerable questions), which led me *almost* to solutions to 2 problems:

1. Having types for a function which maps various inputs each to a specific output based on the `format` property. This is for the [`format` function](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/1akpsvh/how_to_have_a_typescript_function_where_many/) (called `compile` in that link).
2. Having types for a function which takes an `input.format` property, and the corresponding `output.format` property is scoped to the `input.format` property. This is for the [`convert` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77971149/how-to-prevent-merging-of-types-in-complex-distributed-union-typescript-type), still working on a solution to that.

### Goal

Now I'm trying to compose/combine these two functions (as well as other similar functions) into a single function called `call` that will take JSON with a key for the `action` (convert/format/etc.). I have the [TypeScript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMIEMA2O4DeAUHKZhIgG7CxwC8cA5AMYXWyMA0JZAYtKizwGjAGYChXIgF8iAejlwAcgHk4AUQBKmlZoBccACoALGsDgBJAMpwscMIgDmcALQA+OACswz1lRowNHAAJsCiAJaIwMFwplDARH4AzvAQyDBg6QCM9HDMuDgAFMRktsww4RQG2HgAdBhsAdylkZkwBiWlZOJQgu1MDo5SXd3hOMAdPCOlYELGBmIQEMPT0s1ka1NwaRnpk9NwPX0L3kPrIxHj+wdkszDzTABGWFC1pysjm6Wb0gCURPJFKoNNpdAZ7uEknBapdgLU7sY4JC4JRcOFgpw4IC4ElIsxzAB3czGLDUFFomI7NqHaBwCFQhr+Wj5OqJChJCDjWo4CCOQpU7IwsZwhH-bFaHT6IxxczIxAQexOVweYwwVD4PzsQJQEJhSLRWJmNmIFLbdJtABMuRZRU6pCw5UqiGqBXqjVg5yRiDa1wuEn6jEGHy6sN9NwRC3Ey09309XzIAv6dpD-oWqvVwdKocIWwOEaeL1q6ZwmY2ce4fwBChBkvBxmRQq5CKRUNUhnJOHRmOx6OABQAnkj4AS0jgYo9zDB+2ADVgoQADKLsee1Y0crk8vmJi2NkVzMXV4ESsHSswt2yIOAACUMAFkADI03pCbW6iJRYIAQjXqXSAGZrQKYotgdCoqkwV1+GfGBPSOIQ0zVEtPVYUIFgAHjANxTDwBURygMc0LkTDGBkA9FCsYxRxiEkySPUFNDXTk4U3fl-1qFDgDImsTxMM9kTbWw4AAImeKAhKfPpX1Cd9olqOSfzNGAABZALwYDSlAp0XTqKC+lg1MCygYMOMjJZalEqRKyIUBIFoOd+0QZhDmQRywMvG00K2dtQECRBggZApPQwBAQF8-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-XajblJtdSw+YAAdSa4x16r0ppd3sXXj7mdx-CYfj-9J-gBf4eL-ua+oHVvffe091Tv2giAnAv8r7eyribGuy80ZAI3u1MqjthaNxgVASW1t3bhVDuHSOSDIYxxZk9OAKciEGxIWAbOucC4EAkvBIwcAy7TArsAdgi9qb2Ucs5VyTpGEwFQbg9Ba9MF5S2ByKa+IDCUMNoYNw3AepbGSExbkvJChSKgPiOGX0wZTUvAwkyTBAgpCyBaP8jAWG2FEUITGj04FLxpog-09ijpSxURAVCOIYDEycAjSmTjzaryEJ-b+59L7-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-gPSoEgf-dAKd97QiPvhjCs2Q7nbtWmR3OAAA1XAyAv6bSQ20NWA6ENo2HRuoQuRiPIchDAaWjACojQVhKol3rD3+mVaq8jbRUqSw0KFI55QABC-YrDIEeAAaTDmzMg7H0goZglsCwEsGPOLpirFVIjvUkZgFx5MtG33dAMvJ+GpRf0ztIG9Aw6gQDMBwMgUIOHIrMegoa6jiZGAK0xBYROGwZD5zgIURguCrFqfwRHJjh0IOOY81sFOw6HN9Cc-5wOflXNbA6FZQlS0TTwAsLeX5ABxdQFacu5YsBgETFaLBKDSgAVUMBW3gugcvtgYNRoMmJGDvDa48VAYAuBMBXaIVzXrkh+oI4x69S6L37o07kQo5sQvZbywVorJWysVeq7V+rmhGu-Glrymg9HRsZdNAt-LhW8srYrSoGr626sNd+U1uALWnC9faz4F7XWeu5zWsNxTwTxu3oPWF1K9AtizdpvNorS3zulcu9dmrt2tv3Z23tqAB30vBOI4uq9u7Jt3ofaO5FejUBlJZfs2dPoW5Zn0zjlda6NNkOzAwwm1KlSsNIGzh6hUTOCJ3ReibtPAdYwAxce1hdmcYpYU+lFPIoANBcjARZozxWHeGzrFQSgNt3Ye9LLYo8YADc9IwLJBvdcjlEKIC0wZGBm5N6URgSRKBnF18ALJVuPtSC+1CH7h24UUHC30Gbc3CHq814jwwyOleo9+4hyK4GwN+6glB-H1JCekHiMT3FkL8Xvop9zszf7hchlF0zp16KSaS8MwmMLunTMGXA4XrMxfHX3AMI25wHPybR7RhZtZ-HBPCbE-2CTpBHxqYYTpsvTgADcnP+ht5n0Bgpg54ykADslSfjg-YMFH4l8KLlg7ygJJeFOhQ19B3vNR2jg2U6PnYewWqd+q4+5Xhh6z2GFH+2lsFyOOciBAA), it's a bit too long to post. Essentially it boils down to what is at the start of the playground example:

```
call({
    action: Call.Convert,
    input: {
        format: 'png',
        file: {
            path: 'foo',
        },
    },
    output: {
        format: 'jpg',
        file: {
            path: 'bar.jpg',
        },
    },
})

export async function call<
    T extends Call,
    C extends ConvertInputFormat,
    F extends FormatPrettier,
>(input: CallInput<T, C, F>) {
    switch (input.action) {
        case 'convert':
            return await convert(input as Convert<C>)
        case 'format':
            return await format(input as FormatPrettierInput<F>)
    }
}
```

### TypeScript Error I'm Getting

It throws a TypeScript error at `output.format == 'jpg'`. How do I get it to work in the composed `call` function, combining all these relatively complex types from the nested function calls? It's not absolutely necessary this works, I can just pass an `any` to it lol, but it would be nice to see how one could make this work.

If I tinker around with the TypeScript playground, **I can't seem to find a way to compose the complex nested functions without *some sort of TypeScript error happening*.** I can get it to work fine in plain JavaScript, just add a few dynamic/runtime checks here and there. But getting this to work with TypeScript seems almost impossible. *If it is impossible, please answer with that, with an explanation of why.*

### Basic Expectations

At a high level, I expect to be able to compose these `Call.Convert` and `Call.Format` functions, *each of which is itself a complex function calling further into nested functions*, into a higher order function. This way, I can have a single function called `task.call(input)`, where `input` can be anything typed to any of the `action` types.

In addition, please note that each of these `action` types takes in (1) a similar set of input parameters *in some cases* (like `input.file.path` and `input.format`), but *also* (2) they take in different/extended parameters based on the input keys. Let me elaborate on that a little.

This function call's inputs are first typed based on the `action` property (determined: `Call.Convert`), then the `input.format` property (determined: `png`), then finally the `output.format` property (any extra properties that are unique to converting a PNG to a JPG, such as what to do with the transparent color, etc..).

```
call({
    action: Call.Convert,
    input: {
        format: 'png',
        file: {
            path: 'foo',
        },
    },
    output: {
        format: 'jpg',
        file: {
            path: 'bar.jpg',
        },
    },
    transparentBecomes: '#ff0000'
})
```

So it's like a **multi-property [discriminated union type](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions)**, if there is such a thing.

1. Several properties on the `input` are used to scope the type on the rest of the `input` props.
2. Based on that scope, there can be extra `input` properties specific to that scope.
3. Then the `output` of the function call is scoped to whatever the final input properties scope was...

### Expectations: API Examples

Here are some examples of what I would expect from the API:

```
// NO ERROR: There IS a png -> jpg converter defined here
const output1 = call({
    action: Call.Convert,
    input: {
        format: 'png',
        file: {
            path: 'foo',
        },
    },
    output: {
        format: 'jpg',
        file: {
            path: 'bar.jpg',
        },
    },
})

// NO ERROR: this .file.path is valid, 
// since we have valid output for this Convert call.
console.log(output1.file.path)

// ERROR: There is no png -> html converter defined here
const output2 = call({
    action: Call.Convert,
    input: {
        format: 'png',
        file: {
            path: 'foo',
        },
    },
    output: {
        format: 'html',
        file: {
            path: 'bar.html',
        },
    },
})

// ERROR: this .file.path is NOT valid, 
// ideally it would be typed as `never`.
console.log(output2.file.path)

// NO ERROR: There is an HTML formatter defined!
call({
    action: Call.Format,
    input: {
        format: 'html',
        file: {
            path: 'foo.html',
        },
    },
})

// ERROR: There is NOT a "bar" formatter defined...
call({
    action: Call.Format,
    input: {
        format: 'bar',
        file: {
            path: 'foo.bar',
        },
    },
})
```

### Future API

**Solving for all these would make the question even bigger** than it already is.

In the future I will have an `action` for each of these:

- `Call.Archive`: Takes as input the input directory, and outputs a `.zip` or similar archive file.
- `Call.Generate`: Takes as input an `algorithm` for a hash, and generates that hash given some `text`.
- Many others (40+ other `action` types)...

So the `call` function should be composed of many similar things to the `Call.Convert` and `Call.Format` functions underneath.

### Question

How can I build such a tree of composed discriminating union types, which include type generics and such? I have spent weeks on this problem, tinkering this way and that, but haven't reached a working solution and am currently resorting to just using `any`, like this:

```
call({
    action: Call.Convert,
    input: {
        format: 'png',
        file: {
            path: 'foo',
        },
    },
    output: {
        format: 'jpg',
        file: {
            path: 'bar.jpg',
        },
    },
    transparentBecomes: '#ff0000'
} as any)
```

But I would like for both (1) the **input** to be typed, and (2) the **output** to be typed based on the input. The output to the function call.

I feel like some advanced uses of TypeScript in the wild have solved this problem, I just don't know how. For example, the [zod library](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) is pretty advanced in the types it creates, so perhaps that would implement something like this internally. But I haven't been able to successfully use "inspiration" sources like this to solve this problem yet, unfortunately.

### Update 1

Added a [follow-up discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78024409/ways-of-using-multiple-properties-to-nest-discriminated-union-types-with-generic) and linked [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwVAvLA9gOwG4QE7BQA+UAYungLZyEkDiEm+NEAUKwPQdQDOAFugCuCACZQAcgHkAKlACiAJQWSFrAMZYehIcDCDgARlRQ1iBAAoA3qyi2ocNcACWWAFxQA5Bpz5gHgDQ2dk6YesDu1nZRUABmFNThnmCYAOYBQdGxTggQEVBgNHzuHiFhAHTJaVAAvhk1gVE6YRF1UXFUNMUAVmBpDZlZOXkFwEWepfoVqR41dbXVAJSc3PxCohIy8koq6proOWUI6CnmTfoGZTHZEBWFS8u8AsJiisoKUABGHGpQmOj5qSgAFoAHxQYDAGImLC4Aj4XaYLRQM7AABMxlMSCsdQczjcnm8sL8-VsE0SkQG7QSxUq6QGg1yUEs+UKxTJUyqtSi1RJyP0zSZrTsVM6nghMTplOuw1Z41Ck3FMy5dnmSy4jzWL227zgPCgAAMmLD9eDwGxvDx9jcjicURcrgcRnx7urVs8NrJXipPt8oAB3aB8OC4XjYFLAsGVKAAQXEABFPg4ANYpPBCTAiGD7ChQJx6kQQK5MMTtcECHjQMk8BFIlEAZgxZmxUVxLkwxUJvklpPl5KFthFiQ8PDD3eiDsZzKdbN7ZRHnLmvJRLXpg5p015bWlTJZoxn5Vps25vI+ydT6cz2bwxQAxDEYgAGJ8PjysRYPN3rKSe7X2PWGiBjVNSAaytQ5jlOfl9DrS5rluUYXRWJ51i9d4vh+AMoCDEN5wjAFw1jBNTzUFM00EDMsyOPBc3zQsQggEsc1GdAK1zXtqwtbQoOAAAWRssQpWxW3xLwYS7XkyRXSl4lFYdR03YVtynWUSlneclUXOpl0FVcZKHWkFIHJTdzGVSD2mI8VV5V1kK1N4sPwaB0KgFIEHAPgAAV0BCYA9TzKByILIsGNiHNcNBfDoR8OE8H8ZFMDc0NwwiuJMEITsYurKJXPcryfJ4dwAG0AE4ADYAF03zVJDNS2ezdQNI18BNUAQItMCbUg3R9B42DHTudgbNq786u9ZzMOwwNgAQShQo6CF4U4vluuAABWfiLEE+xHDbYpBzHNdPD4YBKAQMcNALYoAB4wBBPgICQf4-QoUQro4W70nfIb3RG1C-0awDmuA809gOTqUVWsoLogRCNXdP7xsDYNoAACWkABZAAZOaEmAfBPn0A0K0oJwNCORETX8v5tEwLCTuQQc8eo1qQcRLiVtKjbmzsYT208fbeUOjxjtO870Euzwbruh6jn9F6RDej7rJqn7Nj++68Cc30eBCVyIAARUEdA8b1ABJABlKAgvoxjqLRrG6h11IckN42IAK8E8EECBlbhlDfw1rWfj+XgIBJsnNCtujizmqB7cxx2w9J7NEXcYAvZ9qqP1s0adX-Jq8Bas1QLBiCUVKqHxZhwaVf9+znIKHgeGevAxBSRhmGAHMRHQd3MA8QhJoNRAUgoJxRkoE1rZjrBgZrdmwgAdi5rbeeKdumDwFgxxZmldWbigRDHEex4n4p+DgVFVtKsW0sYIc4nQU88FPAAvV8vtruzvQagCgJZku1oy7cUXpXO+aVYafjEL9X8Dd94tzbh3LeXdqI9z7gPLCyNh4IFHngcefBJ5R2CmIWeACloogABwrxxDtESG9O4QB3maYoQZ+DHxwafAh58gxXxvrybweM0p7XQE-OAL84Dvyzt9L8atfy-wLkXNqoMgG2m4hQsBgjgD3BiORWhtNMQWEkrAMwCwdJ2GbuPNQfAoDmHZLzUxW0oimFYqJaKfh3Ca2AIIPA+ixIEFsb2JY9JnHQA8PtDxEAvE+JxjQAJYQgkDBCZ4ehyDGERKibTFJLA4n6ASbYeY7AdGYD0VFIkOTEhZjcQ4uonjvG02ZBOGUe4xTu2AGUCAAAPOAlAwA5CVDUf6lSiSSG4tWWorAiklMHOU9w5B5rVKiLU6JzJobFE6d03pNwyhlH6Q1OZCQRkrTGYU3ReJMlIOyUYhgm8WALLsEs+pUVNHFAMKiOsrz3lvN2Xqa5DDDlhGOawFmGA3HGFXnojsfi-BvigAAMhBUSU27EgVmjIHpMFNCznCPmh-OFaL5pIoBSiyAUBfmpIxS2CFySLl41xfCslLBCX6GrMS6AQzfBMt8sYdlBBTbUHbsQBFvhyBpUFTy4AcZ0BqEEJQe+rKhUEH+cyilikhhmMyNOXg6ddZzDfOwYF4q+VwHbpy-ZNBjAeEPCQDwPQqjWpSE4CUgqPBbz9DMa1ag8CondZ4dS8rDX8ogEq4AZrCBoEtRZa1tqfUeAdRKfVqLxUiuAKa9F4bFTOuNk661z17wxtzTEb1zq-UGqhcm4NoaLUZutVm-N6A83OoLUW9UIdzYADU6Cxz+H6OKpYNA9JyB08eTh3a8DgEmNg-qoWSulbKtKqb5oWpFmdZ1YARDZs8D3NQHSY0EA3QPDp0LS1uJnTK++Fa01HXpjGtd+7aQJpJQG410A0BbSMY44Uel3BPpNb2UN-YGRSXpLYTVWg8GpAA8qfJWluJAfHF+hVKbA0XvmgBxp6rgOge1RB+kUHLK2GIqRC8lEKAAH53BgZ1VEAoIgRC63I78GVHx4S1GPUSZNKqewCg-QOBDSasApr-XpNDSkAPUdlJRnDAw8N4e0jxmJFSy0CZQwkETar5PieaZJlIkHdXZTcmATy3k0o8AY9GPAW8QBXUwEx-AII9Vsd8KeudYaMPvrQ3xpT86hOodXKJ4DdgsPgZ07hvTdg5Mefmt+rzwAVM0DU5OMTgWJPYZC9JsLvG0oMfkxHPADHtNoe6dkEA+XUu6vGcC0NnK9RoFDSjemgrQ3SDNDwT1TgwDAHlaG4NNWMOrK1cFvVXW9L1dOpxhTLDr11H6wVqITs9auxNgxj4IichwEwENyrelmuQFa3gjr42hYsz2+16FTiq4UbK3N3WLsjZLfcCtq063E7hxTqZh7q2IDPYq6ihleNqvGD+xAFGuprH0BpRADy8DD7yqBz18bAj76XcGz9klQOQf8HG7vI6oPXwtg4Xgs+vqgwGBjRfXhMbKAiFWnjuwiOhEDZ1aj6AQOodNwQVj5hSRoet1p7YHIqRmk2coMxvAjsQAi-2DwaQ6AACqFYzMWbgFZ7T9nqhAA) which is similar in spirit to the problem of this specific question, but might shed some light on how to solve this current problem from a different angle.

Comment: I created a [follow-up discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78024409/ways-of-using-multiple-properties-to-nest-discriminated-union-types-with-generic) based on this, which is a more broad look at the problem with multiple possible answers. In there I link to a "starter concept" TypeScript playground, which might help illuminate the problem from a different angle.

Comment: This question and the linked code are too long for me to engage with, and doesn't seem to really be a good fit for SO. (I'd say it risks being closed as needing more focus.) If the example code has hundreds of lines, it's either not a [mre], or the question being asked is not general enough to be useful for future readers.  Could you possibly take this and distill it to its essence so that both the question and the example code could be absorbed without requiring lots of scrolling around? If not, maybe someone will be able to deal with it, but the cognitive load is too great for me. Good luck!